# Simplest way to fill an array in a struct after declaration in one operation

Tags: c, arrays

I have a structure which contain a long array. I know that possible initialize an array when defined:

```
uint8_t array[] = {0x10, 0x11, 0xa2, 0xa5};
```

My question is: is it possible to set all elements of an array after declaration in one operation? Actually, this is a variable of a stucture.

```
struct example
{
    uint8_t long_array[256];
};
```

And after creating an instance I want to set all elements for `long_array` to different values in one operation. If it is not possible, what is the simplest way to set all elements?

There is a pseudocode what I want to do:

```
struct example ex;
ex.long_array[] = {0x01, 0x07, 0x9a, 0xd1, <...>};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can always do memcpy.

Comment: @HotLicks Don't you mean [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset)?

Comment: Why does this have an upvote? The question shows no research effort at all and answers can be easily found by searching

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yea, I thought `memset` is missing there, but it is mentioned in question to exclude it. Doesn't take much to see how it works, though.

Comment: @titapo Well this is not shown in your question. What do you want to set it to? Honestly now it is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @titapo your question never mentions you want to reset your array elements

Comment: @luk32 - Depends on what the init value is.  If you need to init 100 arrays to the same sequence you'd use memcpy from a prototype.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" does not explain how to init an existing array, but rather how to declare and initialize an array in one step. The OP's question specifically asks "is it possible to set all elements of an array *after* declaration in one operation?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Mystruct {
  int a[5];
};

int main() {

  struct Mystruct foo = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
  };
  return 0;
}
```

And you can have more arrays of course.

[EDIT]

About `memcpy`, that is mentioned in the comments, of course it is a working solution, but, you need to have the values in another array, so that you will actually copy this array to the one inside the struct.

Comment: @titapo, you are welcome. However, I am sure that google could have some answers to your question. In order to avoid downvotes in your questions, search better next time and then post. :)

Comment: I started at google, but I dont find information. Originally I wanted to know how it is possible to redefine values for an existing array (not only initialization) Unfortunately my english is not very well. Your answer is a solution for my actual problem, but the really answer for my question is memcpy (with memory overhead) I am courios wether is possible to make it without that overhead but I think it is better to no continue this discuss. Thank you @G.Samaras